# nodejs/typeorm postgresql non-selected column

Tags: node.js, postgresql, select, typeorm

TypeOrm `"typeorm": "^0.3.11"`

nodejs/typeorm postgresql returns non-selected column `test`

logs show:

```
query: SELECT "Test"."name" AS "Test_name", "Test"."id" AS "Test_id" FROM "test" "Test"
```

TypeOrm model/entity:

```
export class Test extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  name: string;

  @Column('boolean', { default: true })
  test: boolean = true;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

controller:

```
await testFind.find({
  select: {                                                                                          
    name: true,
  },
})
```

```
$ curl http://localhost:3000/testApi
[{"test":true,"name":"example01"}, {"test":true,"name":"example02"}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it ended up being `test: boolean = true;` needed to be `test: boolean;`